# Interpreting a Hamiltonian in terms of 'hopping' operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene

I am having some trouble interpreting a Hamiltonian in terms of "hopping" operators. The [Huckel model](http://www.google.com/search?q=huckel+model+graphene) for nearest neighbour interaction in graphene is given by

$$H=-t\sum_\vec{R}|\vec R\rangle\langle \vec R+\vec \tau|+|\vec R\rangle\langle \vec R+\vec a+\vec \tau|+|\vec R\rangle\langle \vec R+\vec b+\vec \tau|+\text{h.c.}$$
where $t>0$ is a constant,  $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are the unit cell vectors for a two-atom unit cell, and $\vec \tau$ is the position of the second atom in the basis, the first atom being at the origin of the unit cell. The position of $\vec\tau$ is $\frac13(a,b)$ generalized over all space.

How can I interpret the different terms in the Hamiltonian as hopping processes?

Comment: Hi mshossain12, this is a homework-like question and I've edited it to add the homework tag.  You need to explain what you've done / tried and do your best to convert this to a conceptual question.

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, and $\tau$?

Comment: Sorry i should have made it clearer. a and b are the unit cell vectors. Its a two atom unit cell and Tau is the position of the second atom in the basis, the first atom being at the origin of the unit cell. tau's position is 1/3(a,b) generalized over all space.